# Bootstrap: make last row stretch to the remaining height and stick text to buttom

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

I have a bootstrap layout like the one on the picture. It has several rows containing columns. The green link is placed inside the column of in the last row. 
Is it possible to make the link to always stick to the bottom of the parent container? It's relatively positioned.
The option is to use position:absolute, but I can't do it because it will overlap other elements if the viewport height is small.
What are the options (except for using @media conditions)?
The html code of this element is like this:

```
<div class="bottom-link">
      <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12">
                  <a class="big-link highlight-pink" href="#"><i class="fa fa-chevron-down" aria-hidden="true"></i> I wanna stick to bottom</a>
      </div>
  </div>
```

Here's the JSFiddle https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/34705/

[image: Example layout]

Comment: it can be done with flexbox. just put your code on jsfiddle. we will try to fix it.

Comment: I've updated my question with jsfiddle snippet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this to work without absolute positioning, you need to give it all the available height (maybe with calc or 100% height) and then use flex like:

```
.parent-of-a {
  /* height: ? You must give all available height here, just 100% won't work */
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-end;
}
```

A code snippet would be helpful indeed.

**Update:**
I have updated your code as follows:

```
.container {
  height: 100vh;
}

.useful-row {
  height: 100%;
}

.col-lg-12.col-md-12.col-sm-12 {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-end;
}
```

New fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ksiabani/wsvc4j31/

Comment: Thanks. This works in jsfiddle, but doesn't work in my real application for some reason

Comment: Your issue is with height, I suppose. In your fiddle you have set container's height to 100vh, but I guess this is not the case in your real application. My recommendation is to use fixed heights for the first two rows and then use calc to provide available space to the last row. Then this code will work.

Comment: It is just like in the real application. I also use viewport height to set the height of the container. Thanks for the advice :)

Comment: But I have no idea how can I use calc() to calculate the remaining space from element's current position to the end of the page

Comment: Suppose you know that the sum of the other rows is 100px, use "height: calc(100vh - 100px)"

Comment: That's what I don't. Their height must be calculated dynamically but must not be less than viewport height (though it might be more)

Comment: You did change container's height from min-height:100vh to height:100vh right?

Comment: No, it's height can differ. From 100vh to whatever bigger value

Answer (score 2):

I have updated your code to show link at last. You need to define the minimum height and flex direction of the main container.

```css
/* Latest compiled and minified CSS included as External Resource*/

/* Optional theme */
@import url('//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css');

body {
    margin: 10px;
}
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

.lastRow {
   margin-top: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="navbar navbar-default">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Bootstrap 3</a>
        </div>
            <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                
           </div>
       </div>
       <div class="row">
               <h3>Test header</h3>
       </div>
       <div class="row useful-row clearfix lastRow">
        <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12">
            <a href="#"> Link to stick to bottom1</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<div id="footer">
      <div class="container">
        <p class="footer-block">Footer</p>  
        </div>
    </div>


#footer {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
}

.footer-block { margin: 20px 0; }

#footer > .container {
  padding-right: 15px;
  padding-left: 15px;
}
```

Try the above code with css or you can use the below bootstrap's build in sticky nav bar.

```
<div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-bottom">
    <div class="container">
      <!-- Your contents here-->
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: as I said, absolute positioning is not an option